# How to use API in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form in the homepage. which contain folllowing fields First Name:

Last Name:

Address:

City:

Country:

State:

ZIP:

Phone:

Email:

After fill out the information and submit to limecrm like a prospect using the API - after this the page needs to go orders page.. Please help me how to use Limecrm API in rails.. Please help...

Comment: why you dont check http://help.limelightcrm.com/forums/261931-apis first and then specify your problem?

Comment: Hi thanks i need to use NewOrderWithProspect request fields:  How can i use this request fields.. Should i use in home page form or should i code in home_controller.. I am new to rails.. Please can you guide me.

Comment: if you are new to rails why you consider doing it as light crm is a php project

Comment: Yeah my friends said in rails we can submit to limecrm  using the API ? is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ruby on rails, you can use any other language, too.
As the documentation say, each method will be handled as POST or GET.

So you build you form, include method,username,password and all other data you want to perform as controls.

Submit this form somehow.

As you want to add this to your homepage you should make 2 forms.
The first form on your homepage, post against your own controller.
Then in your controller create a form which you savely post against the light crm (using ssl, username,password, etc.).

Comment: How could i use include method,username,password perform as a controls? Where can i use username and password? Do you have any sample code.  This is the form i am using..  my controller file is class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
   cookies['AFID'] = {
  :value => request.env['AFID'],
  :expires => 1.year.from_now
}


cookies['SID'] = {
  :value => request.env['SID'],
  :expires => 1.year.from_now
}
    
    #cookies[:AFID] = { :value =>}
   
  end

Comment: If you are that new to rails, you should start from scratch, see this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/. Don't make sense to post any small samples here tho you need to know how to build rhtml sites, maybe partials, write your controller that handle the request, etc. etc.